# R manually change coefficient of nnet::multinom model object

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial

How do I manually change the coefficient of an R nnet::multinom model object?

I tried :

```
S = summary(multi_mod)
S$coefficients = coef_hitl
```

But if I check out the `multi_mod` object, the coefficient is NOT changed.

Also, is there a nice Matrix format of predicting multinomial logistic regression on a new dataset? Something like this so that I could manually do the prediction?

**X * (X'*X)^-1 * X'*y**

Comment: Your code is changing the summary object `S`, not the model. You could try editing `multi_mod$wts` directly, but not sure how well that will work.

Comment: As for for a nice matrix format for multinomial logistic regression, there is no such thing. Even binomial logistic regression doesn't have a general closed form solution. [See here for some details](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/949/7515).